# How do I use jQuery to modify POST headers onclick?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, apache

I have some links, that I want to modify POST onclick. I can accomplish this with a form, but I want to use short-hand jQuery.

Right now, I'm getting stumped with the syntax of jQuery. I know I want to do something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).load('purchase/credits', 'package=3')">Test</a>
```

But, this loads 'purchase/credits' within the `<a>` tag.

So, I thought something like this...

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).post('purchase/credits', 'package=3')">Test</a>
```

But that doesn't work.

Do I need to do form tags, like this?

```
<form action="purchase/credits" method="post">
   <input name="credits" value="3" type="hidden" />
   <submit>
</form>
```

I'm using PHP, jQuery, Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, using `$.post` utility function:

```
$.post('purchase/credits', { package: 3 }, function(responseData) {
    // ...
}).fail(function() {
    // failed
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Since you are using jQuery, you can use jQuery `.on()` method instead of the `onclick` attribute:

```
<a href="#" class='className' data-package="1">Test</a>
<a href="#" class='className' data-package="2">Test</a>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.className').on('click', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('purchase/credits', { package: $(this).data('package') })
                    .done(function(responseData) {
                         // ...
                    }).fail(function() {
                        // failed
                    });
   });
});
```